# how to access variables inside an enum?

Tags: ios, swift, enums

```
class DetailsViewController: UIViewController
{
    @IBOutlet weak var summaryButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var commentaryButton: UIBarButtonItem!   
    enum viewState: Int {
        case summary
        case commentary

        func setVisibility() {
            switch (self) {
                case summary:
                    summaryButton.enabled = true
                    commentaryButton.enabled = false
                case commentary:
                    summaryButton.enabled = false
                    commentaryButton.enabled = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am not able to access summaryButton and commentaryButton: Gives an error saying "DetailsViewController.type does not a have a member named summaryButton"

How do I access summaryButton and commentaryButton?

SOLUTION: This worked for me

```
enum viewState {
case Summary
case Commentary    
}

class DetailsViewController: UIViewController
{
@IBOutlet weak var summaryButton: UIBarButtonItem!
@IBOutlet weak var commentaryButton: UIBarButtonItem!

var currentState: viewState = .Summary {
    didSet {
        switch (currentState) {
        case .Summary:

            summaryButton.enabled = true
            commentaryButton.enabled = false
            break
        case .Commentary:
            summaryButton.enabled = false
            commentaryButton.enabled = true
            break
        default:
            break

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me your solution is backwards. It's strange to have an enum own IBOutlets to buttons.

I would move the outlets and the setVisibility method outside of the enum and into your DetailsViewController. Create an instance variable currentViewState of type viewState in your DetailsViewController, and then make your setVisibility method switch based on currentViewState.